# Is it possible to use Mozilla Persona (BrowserID) with mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, mozilla, browserid

Is it possible to **easily** use [Mozilla Persona](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/) ([Browser ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/BrowserID/Why_BrowserID)) for native iOS and Android apps? Or is it just too much of a hassle getting the information out of the `web view`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **iOS** I just found this: https://github.com/mozilla/browserid-ios - however I haven't tested it, yet.

Also, I didn't see a similar project for Android, yet.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [android-browserid](https://github.com/seanmonstar/android-browserid)

[CouchChatAndroid](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchChatAndroid) is an open source project which uses Persona for authentication.