# Mozilla Persona sign data string

Tags: javascript, mozilla, persona

Is it possible to use Mozilla Persona to sign data (string, token, ...)?

I would like to pass a string of data with the navigator.id.request(), then transfer the assertion on an un-trusted medium and retrieve the data upon verifying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Mozilla Persona (BrowserID) with mobile apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451190/is-it-possible-to-use-mozilla-persona-browserid-with-mobile-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persona/BrowserID is not a general-puropse signature scheme.  For that, you might want to look at [JSON Web Signature](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature/) (JWS), for which there is library support in many languages.

The [`navigator.id.request` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IdentityManager/request) does not provide a way to pass arbitrary data into the provisioning workflow, so the standard Persona JavaScript would not be able to accomplish this.  You would have to use customised JavaScript that provides the provisioning callback with custom data rather than a public key object.

If you get this far, whether you can get the identity provider to sign arbitrary data will depend on how the IdP software treats the public key argument.
For example, the Haskell `persona` library treats the public key argument opaquely; it will certify any arbitrary JSON 'Value' ([see source](https://github.com/frasertweedale/hs-persona/blob/v0.1.0.0/src/Crypto/Persona.hs#L163)).

On the other hand, if the IdP software expects to parse a valid key object in the format generated by the JavaScript mediator code, then you will not be able to sign arbitrary data.

In conclusion: if you host customised JavaScript to pass arbitrary data to the IdP rather than a public key, *and* if the IdP's software treats the public key as an opaque value, then you can sign arbitrary data with Persona.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I'm looking into webrtc identity problem. If the fingerprint of the keypair used in the connection could be verified by the assertion Persona would be great in combination with webrtc.